# Update Needed Report: Snowflake documentation. Create STAGE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In reference the following snowflake page:

- https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html

At the top of the page it indicates:

> **External stage**
>
> References data files stored in a location outside of Snowflake. **Currently, AWS S3 buckets or Microsoft Azure containers are supported.**

Further down the document parameters are described for AWS and Azure and **Google Cloud**.

I don't know if this is the right place to report doc bugs, but I do know these forums are monitored by Snowflake staff.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a question site is not a private company's documentation bug list, and the "Report Doc Issue" button at the bottom at the page that links to **doc-feedback@snowflake.net** is the recommended method to report problems.

It route has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the GCP offering is a public preview, and can be requested for early access, but is not expected to be widely available until early 2020.

The latest availability came out recently: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/announcing-snowflake-on-google-cloud-platform

Happy to pass on the find. Best!